# can anyone help to clear up a command line problem MarkLogic MLCP

Tags: linux, syntax-error, marklogic, mlcp

```
/home/cent/Desktop/mlcp-1.3-3/bin/mlcp.sh import -mode local \
  -host localhost -port 8046 -username admin -password admin \
  -input_file_path /home/cent/Desktop/mls-developer/unit10/top-songs-source/{songs,images} \
  -output_uri_replace "/home/cent/Desktop/mls-developer/unit10/top-songs-source/{songs,images} ,'/home/cent/Desktop/mls-developer/unit10/top-songs-source/images,'images'"
```

Hi All,

I am doing the the MarkLogic University training for Xquery using cent os 7.
I am following the instructrions for windows. I converted the above line but I am getting aan error

```
ERROR contentpump.ContentPump: Unrecognized argument: /home/cent/Desktop/mls-developer/unit10/top-songs-source/images
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an `images` directory? If not make an empty one. Good luck.

Comment: yes there is an images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some support from MarkLogic basically I was using the wrong version of MLCP Content Pump. The correct version is mlcp-10.0.4.2. I still needed to reboot then it worked. Same command as above:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive about this, but I suspect that Linux is expanding this:

```
-input_file_path /home/cent/Desktop/mls-developer/unit10/top-songs-source/{songs,images}
```

to this:

```
-input_file_path /home/cent/Desktop/mls-developer/unit10/top-songs-source/songs /home/cent/Desktop/mls-developer/unit10/top-songs-source/images
```

That is, it's splitting them out to separate arguments, the second of which doesn't make sense to MLCP.

I think the simplest resolution would be to run the two directories in sequence -- load songs, then load images.